# How can I say about my marks at university?

Tags: vocabulary, spoken-english

I want to say to my friends or parents about my marks at university. How can I do it right?
For instance, 
*I've got 9 marks out of 10 for my last homework.*
How can I say about that I got the highest mark for math test?
Where can I find a different combination of examples to say it?

Answer (score 3):

"I've got 9 marks out of 10 for my last homework." sounds a bit strange because of "have" in "I've". It implies a continuous possession so you'd only use that if you're talking about your overall class grade since you continue to have the grade while you're in the class. A homework assignment is completed and graded and you use simple past tense with that:

I got a nine out of ten.

I got a 90%.

I got the highest mark/grade/score in my class (on that assignment).

I've got the highest mark/grade/score in my class. (It means you have the best score in the class regardless of that last assignment.)

I did the best in my class (on that assignment).

---

Unfortunately, I can't think of any examples to point you to... your question is a bit too broad for me to link you to grammar references.